# error to use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

**Version of google-api-java-client:**
google-api-1.13.2-beta.jar
**Java environment:**
Java 6

Describe the problem.

I have a question.
I want to access the Google Drive using the OAuth 2.0 for Devices.
It is an error to use `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"` scope.
I succeed when you use the `"https://docs.google.com/feeds/"` in scope.
I'm wondering do I use the `"https://docs.google.com/feeds/"` to use the "DriveAPI" I.
Is this the correct usage?

**Request:**

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1

client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Response: {   "error" : "invalid_scope" }
```

---

**Response:**

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1

client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://docs.google.com/feeds/

Response:
{
  "device_code" : "4/e6HcZHKPz-eExgLb_Ll9V8qoT1NP",
  "user_code" : "zzwiv48b",
  "verification_url" : "http://www.google.com/device",
  "expires_in" : 1800,
  "interval" : 5
}
```

How would you expect it to be fixed?
I think that can be authenticated in the scope of the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" I.

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices)

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323335/google-drive-sdk-mobile-integration-query)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an h in the protocol. Try **https://docs.google.com/feeds/** instead of **ttps://docs.google.com/feeds/**. Apply the same change to all your scope urls

Comment: Thank you.
I was set to "ttps :/ /" because it was not able to post on the bulletin board in "https://".
I have been working with "https://" in fact.

Answer (score 1):

From the Google documentation about "Using OAuth 2.0 for Devices" (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#allowedscopes):

> When you use the OAuth 2.0 flow for devices, you can access only the following scopes:
>
> - Analytics Configuration and Reporting APIs
> - Calendar API
> - Contacts API
> - Cloud Print API
> - Cloud Storage API
> - Fitness REST API
> - Fusion Tables API
> - Google Sign-In
> - YouTube Data and Live Streaming APIs

I don't see  Drive API in this list and I think it's a reason of "invalid_scope" error

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with.
I've followed the instructions in the developing document, and use **"www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"** as my the scope in the request.
Eventually, I got "invalid_scope" in the response.

So I've try to use **"www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"** as the scope, and it worked!The hint is from :https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth

BUT!! When I use the access token I created to list the google drive account information, I got error code 403 and the message is "Insufficient Permission".

This is what I used to request the account infornation:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?key=$APP_KEY

That really made me confused....